# How to authorize users with credentials in an outside database?

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx

I need to register users that have credentials in a different database. I have been provided with a dll I can use to check the credentials.

Before I set up a membership provider and role provider to login users but I'm if these providers still exist in DNX.

How do I set up a login system that authenticates and gives roles to users?

Answer (score 1):

membership exists in System.Web.Security which is not supported on dnxcore50, so you can only use it in the desktop version of the framework ie dnx451. If you want to be able to use dnxcore50 (cross platform core framework) you should learn about the new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity namespace which is the newer replacement for user and role management.

you could possibly implement your own identity system though you need more than just a dll that can only validate credentials.

or you could learn about implementing an authentication (OWIN) middleware, there are such implementations existing for facebook twitter and other external auth providers that may be more similar if all you are doing is validating existing user credentials, so you could get implementation ideas by studying the code for those.

then again depending on this dll, it may not be possible to use that dll on dnxcore50, so you may still be limited to desktop framework, it depends if the dll is itself compatible with dnxcore50

Comment: thanks for the guide lines Also the app will be deployed on linux so if I want it to be compatible do I have to use only dnxcore? Should I remove the other framework from the project?

Comment: as long as it supports dnxcore50 it should generally be possible to run on linux, supporting dnx451 in addition to dnxcore50 will not prevent it from running on linux, but if you ONLY intend to deploy on linux, it might simplify things to only target dnxcore50